# How to use while in python?

Tags: python

I should only use `while` and `print` to complete the homework. I have tried a different way to deal with that but still stuck.

Expected output:

```
          1
        2 1
      3 2 1
    4 3 2 1
  5 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

what I got instead:

```
          1
        1 2
      1 2 3
    1 2 3 4
  1 2 3 4 5
1 2 3 4 5 6
```

Here is my code:

```
j = 1
i = 1
t = 6
x = 10
d = 1
while i <= 6:
    n = 1
    space = -3
    while space <= j:
        print(" " * x, end="")
        space += 1
        break
    while n <= i:
        print('%d '%n, end="")
        n += 1
    print("")
    i += 1
    x -= 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are almost there. Just count backwards; i.e. change the following line

```
n = 1
```

to

```
n = i
```

and

```
while n <= i:
    print('%d '%n, end="")
    n += 1
```

to

```
while n > 0:
    print('%d '%n, end="")
    n -= 1
```

Also try the one-liner solution for fun:

```
>>> print("\n".join([" " * (7 - i) * 2 + " ".join([str(x) for x in reversed(range(1, i))]) for i in range(2, 8)]))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
x = [i for i in range(1, 7)]
n = len(x)
j =1 
while j <= n:
    print('  '*(n-j), end="")
    print(*x[0:j][::-1])
    j +=1
```

Output

```
          1
        2 1
      3 2 1
    4 3 2 1
  5 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to print reverse order from your current one :

```
n =6
i = 1
tCol = n*2 -1
while i <=n:
    cCount = i*2
    spaceCount = tCol - cCount +1
    s=1
    while s<=spaceCount:
        print(" ",end="")
        s+=1
    t =i
    while t>=1:
        print(t, end="")
        if(t!=1):
            print(" ", end="")
        t-=1
    print()

    i+=1
```

output:

```
          1
        2 1
      3 2 1
    4 3 2 1
  5 4 3 2 1
6 5 4 3 2 1
```

you can change the value of n to get upto any number

Comment: thank you for noticing, I didn't notice that spaces, now I have edited my code